# Conference call in twilio using Php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I want conference chat that if two person talking then any person add someone in conference call using dialer, Here is my code where i am wrong ?

```
$response->say(
    'You have joined the conference.',
    ['voice' => 'alice', 'language' => 'en-GB']
);



$response->dial(
    $vb,array(
    'record' => True,
    'hangupOnStar' => 'true',
    'url' => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    'recordingStatusCallback' => "myurl/phone_module_html.php"
)
);

$dial->conference(
        $roomName, 
        array(
            'startConferenceOnEnter' => 'true',
            'endConferenceOnExit' => 'false',
            'muted' => 'false',
            'record' => 'record-from-start',
            'waitUrl' => 'http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient',
        )
    );
```

Comment: Maybe the docs here would help: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls-php If not, please describe the issue further. What errors do you see?

Comment: @Twisty : i am getting error "Conference Noun cannot be mixed with Number nouns"

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/13000 -> "The Conference noun can only be used once inside a Dial verb"

Comment: Your code does not look like the examples: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#examples-8

Comment: This doesn't seem like all your code. Can you include the entire file that you're using?